# Adding server side code in single page application

Tags: asp.net, single-page-application

I have a single page application, in .net 4 but created from empty web application (Application web ASP.NET .NET Framework -> empty project). I want to add a simple value to the index.html from server side but not from the api.
Can I include c# code into the page?

Answer (score 1):

I first change my web.config to process html file.
[Enabling processed asp net](http://leedjones.co.uk/enabling-html-files-to-be-processed-by-the-asp-net-pipeline/)

After just need to use 
[embedded .net tag](https://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags)

---

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    <buildProviders>
      <add extension =".html" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider"/>
      <add extension =".htm" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider"/>
    </buildProviders>
  </compilation>

<system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="HTML" path="*.html" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG"
                 type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
            <add name="HTM" path="*.htm" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG"
                 type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags